# What does the "\" mean in build.properties?

Tags: java, ant, build

This may be a very basic/trivial question but I can't seem to get a good explanation.

I have a build.xml which used a build.properties file and the setup for the classpath setting have something like this mentioned...

```
# reference the base directory of the project source
project.base=..

# All files generated during a build are stored here
working.dir=/tmp/HelloWorld/working

# final build artifacts are stored here
dist.dir=/tmp/HelloWorld/dist

# HelloWorld shared library project
project.shared=${project.base}/sharedlib

# HelloWorld jar library directory
lib.dir=${project.shared}/lib

# Compile jars are directly referenced by application code.
# These jars are included in the javac compiler classpath.
# Base directory of these jars are ${lib.dir}
schema.compile.jars=\
thirdparty/jaxws/jaxb-api.jar,\
```

What does the "\" above in the schema.precompile.jars do and how does the build know that the base directory is going to be ${lib.dir}?

Regards
Ali.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a "\" is the last character on a line it means the line has been split up in multiple lines. This is usually done with long lines. The following line is a continuation of the line ending with "\". You can delete the "\" plus the following newline character to join the two lines if you like, the information they contain will not change.

With your second question, are you referring to the last comment line? In `build.xml` somewhere there's a reference to `${schema.compile.jars}`. At that place `${lib.dir}` is probably also used as a parameter for a base directory.